# Strange execution order when stepping through Swift code

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift

When stepping through debug Swift code in Xcode, I frequently see the execution order do very strange things e.g. jumping to the end of if statements and back.

It's almost like compiler optimisations are enabled, only they are not - I've confirmed the project settings for Debug builds are "None[-O0]".

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there something funky going on behind the scenes?

Or is it just straight forward lack of maturity of the Swift compiler/UI/debugger?

Comment: I assume its a bug in the Debugger. I saw some posts about this in the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Sure enough: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/252740?tstart=0 Thanks for the pointer